# Understanding a step in solving a homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In an example from a book, a DE is $(x^2 + y^2)dx + (x^2 - xy)dy = 0$. It is solved by using the substitution

\begin{bmatrix}
       y = ux         \\[0.3em]
       dy = x \; du + u \; dx
     \end{bmatrix}

So the equation becomes:
$$ (x^2 + u^2x^2)dx + (x^2 - ux^2)[u \; dx + x \; du] = 0 $$

$$ x^2(1 + u)dx + x^3(1 - u) du = 0 $$

How do they get to this step, for the $x^3(1 - u) du$ part?

When I worked it out, I got $x^2[1 - u][x \; du + u \; dx]$, but I couldn't see how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just algebra.

$$ (x^2 + u^2x^2)dx + (x^2 - ux^2)[u dx + x du] = 0$$

Combining like terms, we arrive at:

$$(x^2 + u^2x^2 - u^2x^2 + ux^2)dx + (x^2 - u x^2)(x du) = 0$$

This reduces to:

$$ x^2(1 + u)dx + x^3(1 - u) du = 0 $$

Regards

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you could distribute everything.

Comment: @BabakSorouh: thank you! Regards

Comment: Excellent: break it down to reveal its simplicity! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you my friend!